# How to know if JSON string can be converted to JSONObject without errors?

Tags: java, android, json

How to handle this so that it wont give the following error

```
JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject(data);
String currentDynamicKey = "7";
JSONObject currentDynamicValue = dataObject.getJSONObject(currentDynamicKey);
```

error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value  at 7 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

json data:

```
{"2":{"id":2,"title":"Battleship game","enabled":"1","connection_alert":"1","prot":"2","port":"6410","analysis":"1","send_data":"Analysis Data box","regex":"\/HTTP\/1.1 404 Not Found\/","send_on":false,"analysis_alert_title":"404","analysis_alert_body":"not found","analysis_alert_body_false":"found"},"7":""}
```

as you can see at the end the 7 in empty. what can I do to check if it is empty?

Comment: Which json parser are you using? Dozens exist, and all of them have a JSONObject or JsonObject class.

Comment: this is an Android application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `optJSONObject(String name)` instead `getJSONObject(String name)`:

**Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONObject. Returns null otherwise.**

And then check returned value.